# Relation between ∆(tetrahedral) and ∆(octahedral), ∆t = 4/9 ∆o

Tags: coordination-compounds

I remember my teacher saying that ∆(tetrahedral) being 4/9 times the ∆(octahedral) for the same ligands and the same central metal ion due to some analogy by number of ligands, but I do not seem to remember it.